# TYPO3 9.5 LTS update function broken

Tags: php, requirejs, updates, typo3-9.x

I just clicked the "Update TYPO3 Core" function in the TYPO3 Backend of TYPO3 CMS **9.5.9** (installed without composer). The AJAX crashed because a require.js call that try to load `/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Modules/Module/CoreUpdate.js?bust=1567682511390` which does not exist.

However the correct path of the file would be without **/Module/** like `/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Modules/CoreUpdate.js?bust=1567682511390`

They had [this problem](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87570) once and marked it as completed but it still appears.

What can I do? Need it to remove the `System > Reports > "Remaining updates"` message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My workaround is: I create the missing directory /typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Modules/Module/ and copy all *.js files from /Modules/ also in /Module. 
Then the "Update TYPO3 Core" works.

Comment: I used a symlink for that. In the Directory: `ln -s ./ Module` Thanks.